# CMB select with data from CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, metabox

I'm using the CMB framework for creating metaboxes (https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress)

and I want to add a select box which prepopulates with titles from a custom post type.  A normal select box looks like:

```
array(
    'name' => 'Test Select',
    'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
    'id' => $prefix . 'test_select',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        array('name' => 'Option One', 'value' => 'standard'),
        array('name' => 'Option Two', 'value' => 'custom'),
        array('name' => 'Option Three', 'value' => 'none')              
    )
),
```

I want to do something like:

```
array(
    'name' => 'Test Select',
    'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
    'id' => $prefix . 'test_select',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => array(
        query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'myposttype' ) )
),
```

where the select options are populated from the titles of a custom post type.. but it's not working the way I though.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that returns an array of arrays that the `options` field expects.

Something like this (untested code):

```
array(
    'name' => 'Test Select',
    'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
    'id' => $prefix . 'test_select',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => get_myposttype_options('myposttype'),
),

function get_myposttype_options($argument) {

    $get_post_args = array(
        'post_type' => $argument,
    );

    $options = array();
    foreach ( get_posts( $get_post_args ) as $post ) {
        $title = get_the_title( $post->ID );

        $options[] = array(
            'name'  => $title,
            'value' => $title,
        );
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: This looks great, should work.. but comes back blank

Comment: Which part is blank? The whole page or just the return value from the function?

Comment: value from the function.  not pulling and information.  Would it be better to create a field type instead and reference it that way? https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Adding-your-own-field-types

Comment: The case on `id` was wrong. I edited the answer with the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'myposttype' );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $title_list[] =  array('name' => the_title(), 'value' => the_title());

endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

array(

    'name' => 'Test Select',
    'desc' => 'field description (optional)',
    'id' => $prefix . 'test_select',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $title_list
)
```

Comment: this returns: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE

Comment: There is a semicolon missing on the end of the first line.

Comment: check now i have corrected the parse error